# Lenovo sources list added to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Tags: apt, updates, lenovo, software-sources

It looks like a lenovo sources list got added to my host without any interaction from me:

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/oem-sutton.simon-banning-meta.list`

containing:

```
deb http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/ focal sutton
# deb-src http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/ focal sutton
deb http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/ focal sutton.simon
# deb-src http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/ focal sutton.simon
```

I have specified my sources list files via Ansible, and Ubuntu was not originally installed on this host. How was this added to my host? I can understand some hardware-specific packages, but the repo is filled with tons of python (and other) extras, and there was no user prompt to accept these repos. If I remove it, will it get re-added, and how can I stop that?

Comment: Sometimes when you install software (e.g. Google Chrome) it adds a source. Did you install anything recently?

Comment: No, nothing installed like that. Esp nothing from Lenovo.

Answer (score 0):

That is hardware support for ThinkPad P14s/P15s on focal. It has been an empty repository until lately [see here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/oem-priority/+bug/1899819) and is now part of the distro.

Still I don't understand why it is explicitly added to apt during update. It is not activated in your "Software & Updates" I presume.(Either in "Other Software" or "Addtional Drivers")

Comment: This is for a P330 tiny.  How does it get added?

Comment: The P330 Tiny has recently been certified by Canonical and, when that happens, there are often hardware enablement repositories that become available. These will often include specific settings and driver packages that will allow you to get more from your system.